# Android 10 Create mediastore entry with a display name containing a dot "." infront EX: .nomedia

Tags: java, android, file, mediastore

Im trying to create a mediastore entry with a dot in front like the tittle says.

The problem is when i try to do this, it puts an underscore "_" infront of the dot, this is not good for my use case, since im trying to create a ".nomedia" file, so the mediascanner will ignore pictures in a folder. Simply creating the file is not an option as far as im aware, with the new scoped storage changes. I do not want to use the  android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" option in manifest, since i want this to be future proof. Heres what im doing so far.

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
private void addNoMediaFileVersion29()
{
    try
    {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "addNoMediaFileVersion29 - called: ");
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues(3);
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, ".nomedia");
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, ".nomedia");
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, "Pictures/" + context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name) + "/");
        Uri destination = context.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

        if (destination != null)
        {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "addnomedia - new uri : " + destination);
            String fileName = "";
            InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileName.getBytes());

            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "copyPicture - destination: " + destination);
            ParcelFileDescriptor file = context.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(destination, "w", null);
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file.getFileDescriptor());
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0)
            {
                out.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
            out.close();
            in.close();
        } else
        {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "addNoMediaFileVersion29 - nomedia file already created: ");
        }
    } catch (Resources.NotFoundException | IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: This problem has been reported here lately. Read stackoverflow pages tagged android. Short: A leading dot is not possible.

Comment: Use SAF to be able to use that dot. But even if you manage your not-scan request will not be honored i'm afraid.

Comment: I know the not scan will be honored, ive tested it simply adding a .nomedia file, only some apps like google photos kinda dont care. And how do i do this with SAF? Any pointers very appreciated!

Comment: How to create a file with SAF? That is a standard action. Examples all over the place.

Comment: same issue!  some android source coder is gild the lily